# Strange Problem from Folland

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having troubles with problem 9a page 155 from Folland's Real Analysis. Here's what it says:

Let $C^k([0,1])$ be the space of functions on $[0,1]$ posessing continuous derivatives up to order $k$ on $[0,1]$, including one-sided derivatives at the endpoints. Show that if $f \in C([0,1])$, then $f\in C^k([0,1])$ iff $f$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$ and  $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f^{(j)}(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f^{(j)}(x)$ exists for $j \leq k$. (Hint: use the Mean Value Theorem).

I can't see why the statement isn't obvious (I mean, I thought that was the definition), in particular I have no idea how to use the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: I think the not so obvious part is the following: start with the r.h.s. of the equivalence, i.e. $f$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$ and the limits exist. Then we must convince ourselves that those limits are indeed the one-sided derivatives at the end points $0$ and $1$. Is that obvious to you?

Comment: The definition is that all derivatives of $f$ up to and including order $k$ exists at all points of $[0,1]$ and are continuous functions. Essentially, you are asked to show that if $g\in C([a,b])$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, and the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g'(x)$ exists, then $g$ is differentiable at $a$, and $g'(a) = \lim\limits_{x\to a} g'(x)$. Everything else is just repetition and symmetry (for differentiability at $1$).